# initialising 2-dimensional array (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to initialise an 2-d array with some objects. And I want the 2nd "dimension" to have arrays of different sizes e.g different powers of to. And my idea is the following code:

```
NodeMatrix=new BNode[n][];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<Math.pow(2,i);j++) {
            NodeMatrix[i]=new BNode[(int)Math.pow(2,i)];
            NodeMatrix[i][j]= new BNode(i);
        }
```

but it doesnt work and I have now other idea how it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize BNode array before you iterate over it.
As an advice, consider if you really want to set length by powers of two, that will grow fast.

```
NodeMatrix=new BNode[n][];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    NodeMatrix[i]=new BNode[(int)Math.pow(2,i)];
    for(int j=0; j < NodeMatrix[i].length; j++) {  
        NodeMatrix[i][j]= new BNode(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your requirement completely. But the below code may help you to understand the 2D arrays in Java.

```
public static void generateDynamicArray() {
        int[][] arr = new int[5][];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[(int)Math.pow(2, i)];
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] +" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, It **cannot** be done in java. 2 d array is nothing but just array of arrays.

One option can be use a list of arrays.

Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaArrayListOfStringArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List <String[]> list = new ArrayList <String[]>();

        String [] arr1 = {"a","b","c"};
        String [] arr2 = {"1","2","3"};

        list.add(arr1);
        list.add(arr2);

        for(String[] arr : list) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay!! Edited the answer.